# Executing two synchronized method by two thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Lets say I have methods `synchronized hi(){}` and `synchronized hello(){}`  method in class `ABC`. and two threads `t1` and `t2` are executing `t1.hi()` and `t2.hello()` respectively. Can they get executed concurrently or any issue is there?

Comment: I think they will not be executed concurrently. I think synchronized method is basically lock by the object itself so once one method get executed, the lock is acquired by the thread so other threads cannot acquire the lock again to execute the other synchronized method.

Comment: Read up on the `synchronized` keyword and the mechanics of synchronization in general. Also note that `ti.hi()` makes no sense of that method is part of `ABC` unless `ABC extends Thread`. In that case `t1` and `t2` would be 2 different instances and they don't affect each other. If both threads operate on the _same_ instance of `ABC` though, both methods can't be executed in parallel (they can be called but one thread would then have to wait) - that is because `synchronized` on method level uses the current instance as its monitor object.

Comment: So ABC extends Thread, or two Threads are working on the same ABC instance?  Please update with some code.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking: Are `t1` and `t2` two different instances of your `ABC` class? or are they two different threads that both are calling methods that belong to the same instance? It might help (a lot!) if you would edit your question to add some actual code.

Answer (score 5):

No, 2 synchronized methods in the same object cannot execute concurrently:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

From the docs:

> It is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave. When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object.

The key here is locking on the object. As Thomas pointed out, presumably `t1` and `t2` are different instances of the same class so they could actually execute `hi()` and `hello()` concurrently.

If `t1` and `t2` are simply 2 different threads calling `hi()` and `hello()` on the same object, then the above semantics hold true and the 2 methods cannot execute in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

> Using synchronized keyword on method declaration uses an implicit
>   object which is the class object in case of a static method or the
>   instance object itself in case of non-static method.

example 1:

```
public class A {
  public synchronized void setName() {
  //
  }

  public synchronized void setAge() {
  //
  }
}
```

Assume there are 2 threads Thread-1 and Thread-2.
Now Thread-1 try to access setName() and Thread-2 setAge()
Let Thread-1 enters 1st and holds the key and Thread-2 will wait till key is available. confused?
So here since no explicit object used for synchronization, the same key is used to synchronized both methods which are

> "The Object of A which is used to access setName() method and setAge()
>   method by Thread-1 and Thread-2 respectively".

```
A a = new A("Name", 1);
Runnable nameR = () -> a.getName();
Runnable ageR = () -> a.getAge();
Thread nameThread = new Thread(nameR);
Thread ageThread = new Thread(nameR);
nameThread.start();
ageThread.start();
```

But this is problem because no other thread will be able to run other methods even though the Thread having key is not accessing it.
So to solve this we need to have separate keys to synchronized getName and getAge method independently.

```
public class A {
private final Object nameLock = new Object();
private final Object ageLock = new Object();
  public void setName() {
   synchronized(nameLock) {
     //
   }
  }

  public synchronized void setAge() {
   synchronized(ageLock) {
     //
   }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!